# Unity3D relative rotation of objects on an axis

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions, euler-angles

In the project I am using IMU sensors to track real player's hand and apply the transformation values onto 3D hand inside Unity.

As IMU sets the Y axis orientation relative to magnetic north of the earth, in the game, hand initializes on specific direction.

What I want is to calculate the offset of IMU's given Y values and 3D hand's original Y rotation, so that I can subtract that value to the 3D model's Y rotation (that will seem like player's initial Y Rotation is the same as 3D hand's). Code would be: `transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, offset, Space.World);`

IMU sends Euler angles (does it well, as I wasn't able to get Gimbal lock)

As I understand, I need to find out angle difference between 3D Hand's initial rotation and IMU's given initial rotation on XZ plane (or through Y Axis)

How do I calculate the offset?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Quaternion.FromToRotation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.FromToRotation.html) to calculate offset, something like:

```
var offset = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, imuUp);
transform.rotation *= offset;
```

Comment: Thanks for considering my question. What do you mean by imuUp?